# excel-parser failed when space in excel filename

Tags: python, node.js, node-webkit

I use excel-parser to parse excel in nodejs, but when filename contains space,  it throw an error.

this is the error message:

```
 "message: "Command failed: usage: %prog [options] infile [outfile]
 ↵convert.py: error: unrecognized arguments: (6).xls
 ↵""
```

my code is here:

```
excelParser.parse({inFile:'d:\1 2.xls',worksheet:1},parserTaokeExcel);
```

how can I parse a excel file whose name contains space using excel-parser?

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the filename in double quotes? `inFile:'"d:\1 2.xls"'`. That's one way the windows command line expects filenames to be escaped.

Comment: If double quotes doesn't work try using ASCII value for space.